# Prepend fancybox with value from custom meta

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using fancybox and need to prepend a link, part of which is a value from a custom meta field. At the moment I have something that looks like this:

```
    <script>
      $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        padding : [15, 15, 15, 15],
        helpers : {
          title : null
        },
        'scrolling'   : 'no',
        beforeShow   : function() {
          if ($(this.element).hasClass('pdf')) {
            this.inner.prepend( '<a class="full-screen" href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/pdfjs-viewer-shortcode/web/viewer.php?file=<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wpb_arch', true ); ?>">View PDF Full Screen</a>' );
          }
        },
        iframe : {
          preload: false
        }
      });
    </script>
```

The prepend is working fine, but it won't retrieve the value with get_post_meta.
Does anyone know how I can get the script to retrieve a php variable? I'm new to jquery and PHP and tearing my hair out.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Extremely crude but hoping to help.

Capture my variable, but not using the jquery script.

```
<?php $payment_fee = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'payment_fee', true ); ?>
```

Use that variable in the argument for my query.

```
<?php 
  $args = array(

    'post_type'        => 'payment',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'payment_status',
    'meta_value' => 'visible',
    'suppress_filters' => true );


  // the query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
```

From there I was able to get it to spit out where I wanted it.

Comment: Thanks for having a look, gave it a whirl but it still won't display. I wonder if it's because the fancybox overlay is used on a posttype archive with a series of really complex loops to bring in child pages. Thanks for looking.